# Cannot fill in a word in google flight website using selenium with C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I trying to fill in the word "**LHR**" in the '**from**' filed in Google flights website.
But after typing the letter L the program exit and finished successfully without any errors.
I wrote the following code:

```
        IWebDriver driver;
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/travel/flights?hl=en-US");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        //Clear the from filed
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#i15 > div.e5F5td.BGeFcf > div > div > div.dvO2xc.k0gFV > div > div > input")).Clear();
         driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#i15 > div.e5F5td.BGeFcf > div > div > div.dvO2xc.k0gFV > div > div > input")).SendKeys("LHR");
```

The program ends in:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you have already seen ,on Google Flight webpage, To and From fields are input and dynamic dropdown options. We need to take close look on the user actions for entering 'From' or 'To' fields. For example user click the field and start typing the 'From Destination' name and Auto suggestion names started listing as dropdown list. Input web-element XPath is changing before and after click. We need to find the XPath for both states and send the text to appropriate element state. Below code is for To destination filed (For reference) Hope that will help you.

```
IWebElement DDEnterTo = WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@placeholder='Where to?']"));
DDEnterTo.Click(); //To field clicked
IWebElement DDEnterDestination = WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@aria-label='Enter your destination']//div//input[@aria-label='Where ``else?']")); // Element state changed hence new XPath
DDEnterDestination.Click();//Clicked on new field state
DDEnterDestination.SendKeys("Dubai"); // Entered the Destination
DDEnterDestination.Click();
IWebElement DDToDubai = WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//div[@class='zsRT0d'][normalize-space()='Dubai International Airport'])[1]"));
DDToDubai.Click();
```